# Departure options after Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, regulations

I got a single-entry Schengen visa for 83 days. By the end of the 83 days, do I have to leave the Schengen area to my home country (Egypt) or am I allowed to leave to any other country  as long as it's outside the Schengen area?

eg: Could I head to Turkey? Or must I first go back to Egypt then head to Turkey? Not to break the Schengen rules stating that you should go back to your home country by the end of your visa.

Answer (score 4):

Visas only care about where you are not (generally) where you're going. The visa is for the Schengen area and just means you must leave that area before the time expires. The Schengen countries don't care where you're going.

Or course, you'll need a valid visa for wherever you're trying to go. (As the airlines/other transport, at least, will check that).